# SQL table merge algorithm

Tags: sql, algorithm, sqlite

I need some help merging two tables in different SQLLite databases.

Let's call the tables `T1` and `T2`.  The tables have identical schemas, but live in different databases. Let's assume `T1` lives in a db named `DB_Target` and `T2` lives in database called `DB_Source`. The Schema for the tables is simple:

> ```
> Table    Columns 
> --------------------------------------
> T1       id, url, cat
> T2       id, url, cat
> ```

I want to merge the two tables, so if the first table contains url from second table just update cat column, otherwise add from url and cat to the first by incrementing id. Straightforward algorithm is:

```
for url2 in second_table:
   url1 = "SELECT url FROM first_table"
   if url1 == url2 then Update first_table
   else INSERT INTO first_table and increment id
```

As both of tables contain about 10K url, it is very long, is there any algorithm for SQL merging???

Comment: just implement the algorithm in the language where you use the **sqlite** library - or tag your question with the language to get more help.. i don't think **2 databases** can be merged using SQL only..

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a 100% clear from your description on what you precisely need, but i think it's something like this:

First, run an update T1 with matching URLS in T2...

```
UPDATE     T1
SET        T1.Cat = T2.Cat
FROM       Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table2 T2 on T1.URL = T2.URL
```

Second insert the extra records from T2 into T1....

```
INSERT INTO Table1 (id, url, cat)
SELECT      T2.id, T2.URL, T2.Cat
FROM        Table2 T2
LEFT JOIN   Table1 T1 on T2.URL = T1.URL
WHERE       T1.URL IS NULL
```

NOTES:

- you didn't specify the database & version you are using.  A Single `MERGE` statement may be an option too.
- It's not clear if ID is an identity/auto-increment field.  If it is, drop the ID from the insert statement

**UPDATE SQL Lite**

I only use SQLLite in passing, so take this with a grain of salt.  However, it appears that you need to issue two `ATTACH DATABASE` ([docs](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html)) commands to make sure  DB1 and DB2 are both attached to the connection. Something like:

```
ATTACH DATABASE filename AS database-name;
```

Once the two database are attached you can prepend table names with the database name.  So let's say you attach Table1 as DB_Target and Table2 as DB_Source the select would evolve to something like ...

```
UPDATE     T1
SET        T1.Cat = T2.Cat
FROM       DB_Target.Table1 T1
INNER JOIN DB_Source.Table2 T2 on T1.URL = T2.URL
```

Here is [an article that walks you through](http://longweekendmobile.com/2010/05/29/how-to-attach-multiple-sqlite-databases-together/) it in a bit more depth.

Comment: i am using sqlite3 there are two tables in two different databases: table1 in db1, table2 in db2